# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while connecting to Embedded Derby Database

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, derby, embedded-database

I'm using Apache NetBeans IDE 11.3 (with JDK 13) and Derby in Embedded Mode. I am getting the following error while connecting to the database:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/iapi/jdbc/JDBCBoot
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(EmbeddedDriver.java:95)
    at Testing.testConnection.main(testConnection.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

Following is the code:

```
package Testing;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;

public class testConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new EmbeddedDriver());

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            stmt.execute("create table test(id int(2) primary key, name varchar not null);");
            stmt.execute("insert into test values (01, 'Jeff'), (02, 'Clint'), (03, 'Mike');");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test;");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("id") + "\t" + rs.getString("name"));
            }

            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know what goes wrong. I think I've not setup the database properly but I'm not sure. I'm new to Derby and Embedded Databases. Used MySQL before but it was a lot easier. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I saw that I didn't add 'derby.jar' to the dependencies before (I was just using 'derbytools.jar'), so I added it and now I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/shared/common/security/SystemPermission
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:93)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:68)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(EmbeddedDriver.java:95)
    at Testing.testConnection.main(testConnection.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.shared.common.security.SystemPermission
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: So, did you download the Derby JAR and add it to your project?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep. I've already added it, still getting the error.

Comment: Derby consists of multiple jars. Exactly which dependencies (or jars) did you add for your application?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have added 'derby.jar' and 'derbytools.jar'

Comment: It looks like you also need to add derbyshared.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) in the comments, adding `derbyshared.jar` along with `derby.jar` and `derbytools.jar` to the dependencies worked and I'm no longer getting that error. I very very much appreciate his help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add to your project (as a dependency) the jar for the Apache derby JDBC driver which can be downloaded here: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html